# Report with Report Writer duplicating last line

Tags: cobol

I find myself sorting an input file, and using a control break to compute some data.  We need headers in the control break, the report writer is duplicating the header each time and I can not figure it out for the life of me.  The write statement in the break paragraph is written twice, but if I use a DISPLAY it is only displayed once. Where am I going wrong with the Report Writer? The break itself is calculating the data correctly (but probably terribly)

```
    environment division.
    configuration section.
    input-output section.
    file-control.
        SELECT corpranks
            ASSIGN TO                                                
                "corpranks.txt" 
            ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
        SELECT out-file 
            ASSIGN TO                                                  
                "report"
            ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
        SELECT sortfile
            ASSIGN TO
                "SortFile".

    data division.

    file section.

      FD corpranks

        RECORD CONTAINS 80 CHARACTERS. 

          01 gf-rec.
            05 first-initial PIC x.
            05 middle-initial PIC x.
            05 last-name PIC x(14).
            05 rank-code PIC 9.
            05 Filler PIC x(15).
            05 rank PIC x(3).
            05 salary PIC 9(6).
            05 corporation PIC x(29) VALUE SPACE.

        FD out-file
        REPORT IS corp-report.

        01 of-rec PIC x(80).

        SD sortfile.
        01 Sortrec.
            05 PIC x(16).  
            05 SR-rank PIC xxx.
            05 PIC x(22).
            05 SR-corporation PIC x(29).


    working-storage section.
        77 EOF PIC x VALUE "N".
        77 current-corp PIC x(29).
        77 total-salary PIC 9(6) VALUE 0.                           
        77 current-salary PIC 9(6).                                
        77 converted-month PIC x(3).
        77 concatenated-date PIC x(28).
        77 formatted-date PIC x(80) JUSTIFIED RIGHT.
        77 formatted-name PIC x(20).
        77 tally-counter PIC 9.
        77 inp-len PIC 9.

        01 current-date.
            05 YYYY PIC x(4).
            05 MM PIC x(2).
            05 DD PIC x(2).
        01 corporation-header.
          05 FILLER pic x(18) VALUE SPACES.
          05 FILLER pic x(13) VALUE "Corporation: ".
          05 ch-corp pic x(40).
        01 corporation-subheader.
            05 FILLER pic x(5) VALUE SPACES.
            05 FILLER pic x(4) VALUE "RANK".
            05 FILLER pic x(5) VALUE SPACES.
            05 FILLER pic x(4) VALUE "NAME".
            05 FILLER pic x(15) VALUE SPACES.
            05 FILLER pic x(6) VALUE "SALARY".                   
        77 csh-underline pic x(40) Value 
        "========================================".
        01 main-header.
         05 FILLER PIC x(5).                                         
         05 header-content PIC x(69) VALUE "Jacksonville Computer App
    "lications Support Personnel Salaries".

    report section.

    RD corp-report.
    01   REPORT-LINE

    TYPE DETAIL
    LINE PLUS 2.
        05  COLUMN 6      PIC x(3)  SOURCE  rank.
        05  COLUMN 12     PIC x(20)    SOURCE   formatted-name.
        05  COLUMN 37     PIC 9(6)     SOURCE   salary.


    procedure division.
    0000-MAIN.

        Sort Sortfile on ascending key SR-corporation 
                      on ascending key SR-rank
                  Using corpranks 
                      giving corpranks.
        OPEN    
            INPUT corpranks
            OUTPUT out-file
        INITIATE corp-report.

       WRITE of-rec FROM main-header.
       ACCEPT current-date from DATE YYYYMMDD.
       PERFORM 3000-CONVERT-MONTH.
       STRING "As of: " DELIMITED BY SIZE
            DD DELIMITED BY SIZE
            SPACE
            converted-month DELIMITED BY SIZE
            SPACE
            YYYY DELIMITED BY SIZE
            INTO concatenated-date.

       MOVE concatenated-date TO formatted-date.

       WRITE of-rec FROM formatted-date.
       PERFORM 2000-GENERATE-REPORT UNTIL EOF = 1.
        TERMINATE corp-report.
        stop run.


    2000-GENERATE-REPORT.
            PERFORM 3100-TRIM-FIELDS
        GENERATE REPORT-LINE
        READ corpranks

            AT END
                CLOSE   corpranks
                        out-file
                MOVE 1 TO eof

            NOT AT END

                IF current-corp = SPACE
                    MOVE corporation to current-corp
                    MOVE current-corp to ch-corp
                    WRITE of-rec FROM corporation-header
                    WRITE of-rec FROM corporation-subheader
                    WRITE of-rec FROM csh-underline
                END-IF

                IF current-corp NOT = corporation
                    PERFORM 2500-CONTROL-BREAK
                END-IF

                COMPUTE total-salary = total-salary + salary
         MOVE corporation to current-corp
         END-READ.


    2500-CONTROL-BREAK.
        WRITE of-rec FROM corporation
        MOVE 0 to total-salary
        .

    3000-CONVERT-MONTH.
        EVALUATE mm
            WHEN "01" MOVE "JAN" TO converted-month
            WHEN "02" MOVE "FEB" TO converted-month
            WHEN "03" MOVE "MAR" TO converted-month
            WHEN "04" MOVE "APR" TO converted-month
            WHEN "05" MOVE "MAY" TO converted-month
            WHEN "06" MOVE "JUN" TO converted-month
            WHEN "07" MOVE "JUL" TO converted-month
            WHEN "08" MOVE "AUG" TO converted-month
            WHEN "09" MOVE "SEP" TO converted-month
            WHEN "10" MOVE "OCT" TO converted-month
            WHEN "11" MOVE "NOV" TO converted-month
            WHEN "12" MOVE "DEC" TO converted-month
            WHEN OTHER MOVE mm to converted-month
        END-EVALUATE.

    3100-TRIM-FIELDS.
        INSPECT last-name TALLYING tally-counter FOR trailing
            spaces.

            COMPUTE inp-len = LENGTH OF last-name - tally-counter

            MOVE last-name(1: inp-len) to formatted-name

            STRING last-name(1: inp-len) DELIMITED BY SIZE
                SPACE
                first-initial DELIMITED BY SIZE
                INTO formatted-name
          MOVE 0 TO tally-counter


    end program Program2.
```

Some report output: (at the beginning header, csh-underline is the last thing written, the === underline displays twice.  At the corporation control breaks, the next corp name is the last thing written, and is written twice)

```
Jacksonville Computer Applications Support Personnel Salaries
                                                As of: 18 FEB 2015

Corporation: Alltel Information Services
RANK     NAME               SALARY
========================================
========================================

 EVP   COLUMBUS C               100000

 SVP   ADAMS S                  042500

 VP    REAGAN R                 081000

 VP    FRANKLIN B               080000

 A&P   FORD G                   060000

 A&P   HAYES R                  050000

 A&P   JACKSON A                057600

 A&P   TYLER J                  069000

 A&P   HARRISON B               052000

 A&P   TAFT W                   070500

 A&P   HOOVER H                 035000

 A&P   PIERCE F                 044000

American Express
American Express

 EVP   JOHNSON L                098000

 SVP   CLINTON W                086000

 VP    ROOSEVELT F              072000

 A&P   HARDING W                040000
```

....

Comment: If you want a hint, think of the old joke: Patient "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do this!"; Doctor "Don't do that then".

Comment: OK, I think it is something more fundamental. The Report Writer can make your entire report, headings, column headings, page numbers, break totals, final totals. However, you have made a very simple report with just a detail line, and the rest you are doing yourself with WRITE. Do you *have* to use the Report Writer? If yes, then you should define the entire report and let it do everything. If no, then remove the REPORT and just do a simple WRITE for your detail lines. Let us know on these questions, and the compiler/OS information.

Comment: Some sample input and the output you get would be useful as well.

Comment: Another assumption I'm making currently is that the line is duplicated on each break. However, the title refers to "last line", which may be taken to mean "last line only, the other breaks are OK". Can you clarify that, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a link to some Report Writer documentation from Micro Focus. It is not the only documentation they provide, but it is all that I have scanned through: http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.studee60win%2FGUID-48E4E734-F1A4-41C4-BA30-38993C8FE100.html

If you loot at Report File under Enterprise > Micro Focus Studio Enterprise Edition 6.0 > General Reference > COBOL Language Reference > Part 3. Additional Topics > Report Writer you will see this:

> Report File
>
> A report file is an output file having sequential organization. A
>   report file has a file description entry containing a REPORT clause.
>   The content of a report file consists of records that are written
>   under control of the RWCS.
>
> A report file is named by a file control entry and is described by a
>   file description entry containing a REPORT clause. A report file is
>   referred to and accessed by the OPEN, GENERATE, INITIATE, SUPPRESS,
>   TERMINATE, USE BEFORE REPORTING, and CLOSE statements.

Although this does not definitively say "Don't use your own WRITE statements and hope that they will work" I think it is clear that you should not. What happens when you do that is not defined, or is "undefined behaviour".

You are getting repeated lines before a break, and after a break, exactly where the Report Writer will be checking if there is anything it needs to do. Although I know nothing at all about the implementation of the Report Writer in Micro Focus COBOL, I am pretty certain that you have correctly identified that the repetition happens and is beyond your control. I think the above quote confirms that, and within other parts of Micro Focus's documentation this may be made more explicit.

You either need to use the Report Writer fully (if the task is to use the Report Writer) or not use it at all. You can't mix automatic and manual on the same report file, it seems, and that makes sense to me.

Remember, it does not matter that *some* of your WRITE statements seem to work, because this is a computer and you need them *all* to work.

Some general comments on your program:

In main-header you have a FILLER without a VALUE clause, which can cause problems when written to a file for printing. Whether that is way those five bytes don't show on your output or whether it is due to formatting in the posting here, I don't know.

Also in main-header you have a long literal, continued onto a second line. I can't see the continuation marker, and that may be a feature of how it is done in that Micro Focus COBOL, but it always makes things easier if literals are not continued. Define two smaller fields one after the other, with smaller literals which taken together make up the whole.

You have this:

```
COMPUTE total-salary = total-salary + salary
```

This, however, is considered clearer:

```
ADD salary TO total-salary
```

You are using STRING. You should be aware that the data-transfer from the sending fields ceases when the receiving field is filled, or when all the sending fields have been processed. In the latter case, automatic space-padding is *not* carried out, unlike the behaviour of a MOVE statement. You need to set your receiving field to an initial value *before* the STRING is executed, else you will retain data from the previous execution of STRING when the current execution of STRING has less actual data.

After the STRING you do this:

```
MOVE 0 TO tally-counter
```

This means your INSPECT, several statements earlier, but where tally-counter is used, is relying on a previous value for tally-counter for the code after that to work. This is not good practice. Make tally-counter an initial value *before* it is used in the INSPECT.

If you go with the Report Writer your PROCEDURE DIVISION code will be significantly reduced, because the definition of the report elements defines the automatic processing.

---

The Report Write feature of COBOL is very powerful. It allows you to define a complex report in the REPORT SECTION of a COBOL program, with headings, column headings, detail lines, control-break totals etc. In the PROCEDURE DIVISION you only need as little as make the source-data available (say with a READ) and then GENERATE the report, and COBOL does the rest for you.

However, you have defined a very simple report, and are attempting to do headings, totals etc yourself. I have never done this, and don't know if it works in general, or if it works for your compiler.

From your testing, it seems like there may be a problem with doing this, and it may be, erroneously, repeating the line you yourself have written. You need to check that that particular line is not output elsewhere in your program.

We need to see the outstanding answers to questions from comments, and, unless it is an excessive size, your entire program.

If your exercise is specifically to use the Report Writer, then I think you need to define a more "complex" report, which will produce, automatically from the definition, everything that you want.

If you do not have to use the Report Writer for this exercise, don't use it, just do the detail-line formatting yourself and WRITE it as you are already doing for headings and totals.

---

On the assumption (later proved false) that you were using the Report Writer to do everything you need, the problem would have been manually writing to the same output file that the Report Writer was using.

If using the full features of the Report Writer, simply make this change and remove any other WRITEs to that output file, and use the Report Writer features for everything:

```
2500-CONTROL-BREAK.
    MOVE 0 to total-salary
    .
```

Comment: Valid points, just wanted to be transparent, will think through it better next time I seek help from a community, and will up vote when I can add the solution after work.

Comment: And for what it's worth, I do care about understanding any language I'm working with, frustrated about chasing this bug for hours on end and let it get the best of me. Sorry if I offended you, and thanks for your help. Well, if I remove the write statement from the control break then I don't have any header output, as opposed to duplicate.  After some fiddling, report seems to just re write the last Write statement I use.

Comment: OK, we're going to need to see the full report definition then. I had assumed you were telling the report to write at the breaks, so that your own WRITE was superfluous but producing identical lines. When you put in the DISPLAY, so see only one because the Report Writer code is doing the other.. Seems to be something a bit deeper than that, however, if that didn't fix it. What compiler is it, and OS?

Comment: Added entire program, example report output

Comment: OS is Windows Server 2008 RD Datacenter, compire is Microfocus Visual Cobol for Eclipse